# Compare installed Joomla code to default source code in bash

Tags: php, bash, joomla, compare

I am looking for an easy way to compare a current Joomla installation code against the default Joomla code you would get when you download Joomla from the official website.

I did some searching but was unable to find anything related to my question, I do know how to use bash and compare 2 files but is it possible to compare 2 directories and list the differences in the code? This can be very useful if trying to find what was added to a core Joomla file for example.

Answer (score 3):

The `-r` flag to diff will recurse through directories.

If you just want to know which files differ, you can `diff -qr /source/dir/ /target/dir/`.

See the diff man page: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?diff